# Value of absolute function under the curve

Tags: calculus

How do I calculate $\iint |xy|\ dx dy$ bounded by the curves $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x^2+4y^2=1$? I do know how to integrate absolute function when they are simply parabolas or like that but this one is quite messy.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Because of the symmetry in the region, integrate over the 1st quadrant and multiply the result by 4. Then, $|xy| = xy$ and you are integrating
$$
\iint_A |xy| dx dy
 = 4 \int_{x=0}^{x=1}
     \int_{y = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1-x^2}}^{y= \sqrt{1-x^2}} xy\ dx\ dy,
$$